# How to translate syntatic parse to a dependency parse tree?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, dependency-parsing, link-grammar

Using [Link Grammar](http://abiword.org/projects/link-grammar/) I can have the syntaxic parse of sentences something like the following:

```
    +-------------------Xp------------------+
    +------->WV------->+------Ost------+    |
    +-----Wd----+      |  +----Ds**x---+    |
    |     +Ds**c+--Ss--+  +-PHc+---A---+    |
    |     |     |      |  |    |       |    |
LEFT-WALL a  koala.n is.v a cute.a animal.n . 

    +---------------------Xp--------------------+
    +------->WV------>+---------Osm--------+    |
    +-----Wd----+     |  +------Ds**x------+    |
    |     +Ds**c+--Ss-+  +--PHc-+-----A----+    |
    |     |     |     |  |      |          |    |
LEFT-WALL a  wolf.n is.v a dangerous.a animal.n . 

    +--------------------Xp--------------------+
    +------->WV------>+--------Ost--------+    |
    +-----Wd----+     |  +------Ds**x-----+    |
    |     +Ds**c+--Ss-+  +--PHc-+----A----+    |
    |     |     |     |  |      |         |    |
LEFT-WALL a   dog.n is.v a faithful.a animal.n . 

    +-----------------------Xp----------------------+
    +------->WV------->+----------Osm----------+    |
    +-----Wd----+      |   +-------Ds**x-------+    |
    |     +Ds**c+--Ss--+   +--PHv--+-----A-----+    |
    |     |     |      |   |       |           |    |
LEFT-WALL a monkey.n is.v an independant.a animal.n .
```

The problem with this that it's not possible AFAIK to make sens
of that output programmatically; It seems like the way to go
is to convert that syntaxic output to a dependency parse tree
how can I achieve that?

Comment: That's a whole PhD topic by itself ;P

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at RelEx ([at GitHub](https://github.com/opencog/relex)).

From link-grammar at Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> The semantic relationship extractor [RelEx](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/RelEx_Dependency_Relationship_Extractor), layered on top of the
>   Link Grammar library, generates a **dependency grammar** output by
>   making explicit the semantic relationships between words in a
>   sentence. Its output can be classified as being at a level between
>   that of SSyntR and DSyntR of Meaning-Text Theory. It also provides
>   framing/grounding, anaphora resolution, head-word identification,
>   lexical chunking, part-of-speech identification, and tagging,
>   including entity, date, money, gender, etc. tagging. It includes a
>   compatibility mode to **generate dependency output** compatible with
>   the Stanford parser, and Penn Treebank-compatible POS tagging.

Comment: I don't understand how relex works, that why I am re-asking the question on how do to this.

Comment: It seems to me ReLex is a dictionary that builds on the flat links into a hiearachical data structure. To get started I don't know how ReLeX encodes this hierarchical datastructure.

Comment: It seems to me based on the documentation from above, is that ReLeX is a graph pattern matcher built ontop dynamic programming. What algorithm does it use to match predicates?

Comment: @amirouche I recommend that you post RelEx-related questions to the [OpenCog](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/opencog) discussion group, since several RelEx experts (including its authors) are there.

Comment: I'm not sure what I don't understand ^^'